# why its paining in the shoulder blade after shoulder press, how to get rid of it?

Tags: weightlifting, shoulders

I have been resuming exercising in GYM, after a long time (approx 3 years). I started with mix light weight exercise including, Biceps, Triceps, Chest, Shoulder+Back. Now after two weeks (10 days, Saturday and Sunday rest), I was feeling strong and I have started, separate work routine for separate body part. Monday Biceps, Tuesday-Triceps, Wednesday-Chest and Thursday-Shoulder Back.Its been two weeks, I have been repeating this schedule. I set weights so that I can do 3 sets, and each set should have these many reps 12-10-8 (I will increase eventually after month or two).

Today, when I was doing shoulder press, I have felt pain in my left shoulder blade (as per my experience it will go but will take so much time). Pain comes only when I am lifting the rod up.But when I simply leave rod on shoulder or coming down from top, pain is very minute. Also when I don't have weights (I am relaxing ), I squeezing my back or say contracting/joining both blades together I don't feel any pain.

I don't understand whats the reason of this pain and how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pain in the shoulder blade can be indicative of many types of problems ranging from a simple muscle strain to a torn rotator cuff. From your description, the pain is not yet problematic, so, I would continue to monitor it and avoid movements (eg. behind the neck press) that can exacerbate the problem. Try doing other movements for shoulders

Comment: Correct, if I recall, **shoulder press behind the neck** has always been a problem. Any alternate exercise for it in that area of body?

Comment: Side lateral raises with a dumbbell will work the deltoids.  You can also try a seated military press with dumbbells.  Or, if you have access to one, a Smith Machine might be helpful because it prevents the bar from shifting forward or backward during the pressing motion.